# How to detect lines for match the following from images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to detect the lines joining the points and extract the coordinates of the points that are joined by the line.
But the code is just considering the all lines as single along with the points.

Input image

[image]

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read image. 
img = cv2.imread('match.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
count = 0
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150) 
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 400 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 600:
        print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        count+=1
# Convert the image to RGB format
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Display the image with circles and lines
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title(f'Number of lines detected: {count}')
plt.show()
```

Output image

[image]